# Having problems with installing py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.6.exe

Tags: python, py2exe

I just have installed py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.6.exe.
When i started it it says that

```
python version 2.6 is required , which was not found in the registry.
```

But i have python2.7 installed at C:\Python27.
What should i do ?

Comment: For Python 2.7 try downloading and installing [`py2exe-0.6.9.win32-py2.7.exe`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download python 2.6.

If a binary isn't meant for python 2.7, there's nothing you can do to change that.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add your Python version to *path* which one do you want to use.

> [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Check this one.

Comment: Can u give me a suitable version of py2exe for python27 on windows 8

Comment: @OsmanMalik have you considered: http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/